# C# AutoFac Inject Without Http Context (Outside Controller)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac

My class Is waiting for a Interface but I need initialize a class from a job in the **Application_Start**.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Bootstrapper.Run();
    JobScheduler.RunJobSchedule();
}
```

On Bootstrap.Run() I have the container builder. like:

```
 private static void SetAutofacContainer()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<DbFactory>().As<IDbFactory>().InstancePerRequest();

    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(DashboardService).Assembly)
     .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
     .AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest();

 IContainer container = builder.Build();


            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
}
```

And on JobScheduler.RunJobSchedule(); I will initializate my Jobs.

My Job need Instantiate the **DashboardHelper** class with **IDashboardService**

```
 public class DashboardHelper
    {

        public IDashboardService dashboardService { get; }

        public DashboardHelper(IDashboardService dashboardService)
        {
            this.dashboardService = dashboardService;
        }
   }
```

My Job Class:

```
public class ReportWeeklySenderJob : IJob
    {        
        public IDashboardService dashboardService { get; set; }

        public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            this.dashboardService.Mymethods();

        }
    }
```

however I can not inject this dependency because the **http context** has not yet been created.

It should be a stupid question, but I could not solve it.

Comment: Well, if you need those things to be created before there's any request then you should not to register them as InstancePerRequest(). Probably it should be InstancePerLifetimeScope() but it's not really clear what you're doing. If you cannot do that then I'd say you have a design problem which you need to solve instead of this one.

Comment: This sounds a lot like [the FAQ about sharing registrations between web apps and non web apps](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html#sharing-dependencies-across-apps-without-requests).

Comment: thanks. I will check it